# Realm IOS Swift Filter Objects

Tags: swift, filter, realm

is it possible to make a Realm Query containing a calculation?

I have an Table with some Objects

i.e.

```
class fruit{
 dynamic var name  = ""
 dynamic var normaWeight  = Int()
 dynamic var minWeight  = Int()
 dynamic var maxWeight  = Int()
}
```

Now i want fo find all fruits which normaWeight < 0.7*maxWeight

```
let allFurit = try! Realm.objects(fruit.self).filter("normaWeight < 0.7*maxWeight")
```

but this Query breaks!
Is it not possible to create an Filterquery like this??

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do like this, because of this way of code is not supported in Realm. So, you can write this logic via closure:

```
let realm = try! Realm()
let allFurit = realm.objects(fruit.self).filter({ $0.normalWeight < 0.7 * $0.maxWeight })
```

Comment: That filter won't work, you need to cast both properties to `Double` for the multiplication and comparison to work.